# I am making a Discord bot using Javascript. I am using a .env file and the dotenv library for security. I am getting an error with importing dotenv

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making my first Discord bot using Javascript. I decided to use a `.env` file to hide my token so I can push the files to Github. To do that I had to use the `dotenv` library. When I try to import that library, I get an error.

> import { config } from 'dotenv'; ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I get this error with the first import statement only, I know that when I switch them I get the same error but with the other one.
(I am using nodemon, Discord.js and dotenv only)

```
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import { Client } from 'discord.js';

config();

const client = new Client({ intents: ['Guilds', 'GuildMessages'] });
const TOKEN = process.env.t;

client.login(TOKEN);
```

Here is my code.

What did I do wrong?
How do I fix this?
How do I prevent this in the future?
Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Welcome to SO, thank you for asking a question. One thing, could you give your post a better title? And also include some more environment details, such as Node versions? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "type": "module" to your package.json file.

or

```
<script type="module" src="your script addres"></script>
```

or use require

```
const config = require('dotenv')
```